# how to tween an objects vertices in three.js

Tags: three.js, tween.js

Hi i need to be able to tween the 'height' of an object. I've looked around and it seems like i need to individually tween the vertices that have a .z value equal to the current height to their new height.

this is what i've got so far but nothing is happening. I call tweenVertex in a loop on every vertex that has a .z value equal to the old height.

```
var tweenVertex = function(object, vertex, height){
    object.geometry.dynamic = true;
    new TWEEN
    .Tween({amount: vertex.z})
    .to({amount: height}, 2000)
    .onUpdate(function () {
         vertex.z = this.amount;
    })
    .start();
    object.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;};
```

Comment: why don't you tween the scale of the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More things here, set tween as variable, don't use object declaration in tween vars, declare new numeric vars and then run tween as array.
At last, don't set parameters in object manually like scale = xx, always use function scale.set(vals), there is more operations to do on changing the attribute, like lighting, materials, all must be updated, class function do it for you any you never have troubles after update three.js release

```
from = 10;//vertex.z
to = 15;//height

var tween = new TWEEN
    .Tween({amount: from})
    .to({amount:to}, 2000)
    .onUpdate(function () {
         //vertex.z = this.amount;
object.scale.set(0,0,this.amount);
    })
    .start();
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! It did the trick, although i ended up having to do a translate instead of the scale.